# How do you say "professional in everything"

Tags: phrase-request

I am trying to solve a TOEFL writing task from past test:
"Do you agree or disagree with the following statement? Parents are the best teachers. Use specific reasons and examples to support your answer."

I started with:
"I disagree with the statement. Parents cannot be professional in everything...."

But I didn't find much used example of the phrase "professional in everything" on Google search.
Is there more appropriate phrase?

**[EDIT]**
Thank you for the comment. So I should start with:
"I disagree with the statement. My reason is that parents cannot be professional in everything.
..."
**[EDIT]**
Then let me correct as following: 
"I disagree with the statement. My reason is that you can learn more and deeper from professional teacher than from non-professional one and that parents cannot be professional in everything. For example, ..."
Is that okay?

Comment: The 'professional' doesn't mean the best. And the question asks you if parents are the best.

Comment: You still haven't linked not being professional with not being the best teachers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Professional" is the wrong word in this context. Professional doesn't mean "skilled," professional means "a trained/experienced person doing work for money," which doesn't make sense here. (I see how it's confusing, as many people paid to do work are skilled at their jobs.) You need a different word. Are you thinking of "proficient"?